# Why does the style not change from state?

Tags: reactjs

I have a login form. And once I connect I want to hide it.
I wrote the code-

```
     let displayConnected = "display";
     let displayNotConnected = "none";
     if (! cookies.User) {
         displayConnected = "display"
         displayNotConnected = "none";
     }
     else {
         displayConnected = "none"
         displayNotConnected = "display";
     }
```

```
                 <div style = {{display: displayConnected}}>
....
</div>


                 <div style = {{display: displayNotConnected}}>
...
</div>
```

Once I connect, the state changes (I checked it ..) and the first form disappears.
But the second form that is supposed to appear, does not appear. Only if I do refresh does it appear.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: The css property `display` doesn't take a value `display`. If you want an element to be displayed, you give it `display: block;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `block` instead of `display`. The css property `display` doesn't have `display` as a valid value.

```
let displayConnected = "block";
let displayNotConnected = "none";
if (!cookies.User) {
    displayConnected = "block"
    displayNotConnected = "none";
}
else {
    displayConnected = "none"
    displayNotConnected = "block";
}
```